# Laravel route when where condition is false

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have the next code:

```
Route::get('/{lang}/user/sort-by-{class}', function ($lang,$class) {
        return view('users.list',compact("lang","class"));
})->where('class', '[a-z]+');

Route::get('/{lang}/user/{user}', function ($lang,$user) {
        return view('users.user',compact("lang","user"));
});
```

When condition in where is false, how can I send it directly to 404 when sort-by- is for example a number? The problem is that it goes to secondary route as an user.

For example:

/en/user/sort-by-name is ok

/en/user/sort-by-4446 must show 404 page

I know that i can do another route just between them with

```
Route::get('/{lang}/user/sort-by-{class}', function ($lang,$class) {
        return \Response::view('errors.404',array(),404);
})->where('class', '.*');
```

but this seems ugly, i would like in **same sentence**

Comment: Why do you used other route for showing error? I think if your route does not match where() condition it will automatically through 404 page. You have to just create "errors" folder in your resources directory and then after you need to create 404.blade.file inside that folder.

Comment: the problem is that i have another valid router after with this: Route::get('/{lang}/user/{user}', function ($lang,$user)  .. then it gets in... i'm going to explain it better, thanks.

Comment: I have edited and commented it better.

Comment: i think you should change your route for `user` like `Route::get('/{lang}/user/user_{user}'`

Comment: `[^a-z]+` is the opposite of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you may do this

```php
Route::get('/{lang}/user/sort-by-{class}', function ($lang,$class) {
    if (is_numeric($class)) {
        abort(404, 'Your reason');
    }
    return view('heros.list',compact("lang","class"));
});
```

Though, using closures in routes is a bad practice because they cannot be serialized in production mode. That's why you should use a controller to return your view, and assign a middleware to this route which will check your `class` and abort the request if needed.

Comment: that would not work since where is a regular expresion and it would check only for characters

Comment: well, numeric was just an example, it can be symbols or any other thing.. i just want the opposite to that regular expresion... , i know that i can do it inside the route using php, but that was not the idea :(

Comment: I got you 2 workarounds on 1 single route, I don't know what you want else